# mysql select join format from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join

I'm trying to select data from one table based on a date range of data from another table.

First table: clients with fields firstname, lastname and telephone.

Second table:  orders with a field date

I need to get a list of all clients first name, last name and telephone numbers who have orders placed between 2019-12-1 and 2019-12-16.

I've tried many iterations of this mysql select but get way too many hits.

```
SELECT clients.firstname, clients.lastname, clients.telephone 
from clients 
JOIN orders ON date BETWEEN '2019-12-1 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-16 23:59:59'
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the relation between orders and clients? There should be a foreign key in the orders table that references the clients table, but you did not describe that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that the `orders` has a foreign key column that references the client each order belongs to, and that this column is called `client_id`. Without this, your schema would not make sense.

I would solve this with `exists` and a correlated subquery that ensures that the given client placed at least one order during the concerned date range.

```
select 
    c.firstname, 
    c.lastname, 
    c.telephone 
from clients c 
where exists (
    select 1
    from orders o
    where 
        o.client_id = c.client_id
        and o.date >= '2019-12-01'
        and o.odate < '2019-12-17'
```

Notes:

- this makes use of the half-open strategy to compare the date, which is a good practice in this kind of situation.
- this query would take advantage of an index on `orders(client_id, date)

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick!